# ASP.NET MVC и библиотека MediatR, странное поведение

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, android-asynctask, mediatr

В одном из проектов подключена библиотека [MediatR](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MediatR).

Используя абстракции из данной библиотеки определил команду:

```
public class TestCommand: IRequest
{ }
```

и обработчик данной команды:

```
public class TestHandler : IAsyncRequestHandler<TestCommand>
{
    public Task Handle(TestCommand command)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            // Здесь намеренно бросается исключение.
            throw new ApplicationException();
        });
    }
}
```

Далее в контроллер инжектится сам `IMediator`, через который мы можем вызвать нужный обработчик для конкретной команды.

Контроллер:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMediator _mediator;

    public HomeController(IMediator mediator)
    {
        _mediator = mediator;
    }

    public  ActionResult Index()
    {
        try
        {
            // Передаем команду, тем самым вызываем обработчик данной команды - TestHandler.
            _mediator.Send(new TestCommand()).Wait();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Сюда никогда не попадаем 
        }

        return View();
    }

}
```

Суть проблемы:

Как можно заметить, в методе `Handle` класса `TestHandler`, который обрабатывает команду `TestCommand` создается и возвращается новая задача, в которой просто бросается исключение `ApplicationException`.

Далее в экшене `Index` контроллера `Home`, к возвращаемой из `TestHandler.Handle` задаче применен метод `Wait()`, который должен дождаться ее выполнения. Так как в возвращенной задаче бросается исключение `ApplicationException` мы по идее должны попасть в блок `catch`, но этого **не происходит**, вместо этого, такое ощущение, что возникает какой-то `deadlock`.

Собственно вопрос, это баг в библиотеке или я что-то упустил и не заметил и данное поведение нормально?

P.S. Если заменить

```
 _mediator.Send(new TestCommand()).Wait();
```

на

```
await _mediator.Send(new TestCommand());
```

то поведение будет ожидаемым, т.е. мы попадем в блок `catch`. Но лично мне хотелось бы понять, почему код перестает работать если используется метод `Wait()`

Comment: А если там вместо `.Wait()` использовать `await` ?

Comment: C `await` все работает хорошо (нужно было наверное это сразу отразить в вопросе), но мне не понятна именно причина, по которой перестает работать когда я вызываю метод `Wait()`

Comment: Насколько я помню из теории: чтобы работал перехват ошибки асинхронной задачи требуется чтоб задача была не `void`, т.е. возвращала `Task` и требуется использовать `await`. А вот использование `.Wait()` просто блокирует поток, т.к. ожидается благополучное окончание задачи, а его не происходит, и получается блокировка.

Comment: Нет, задача должна завершиться со статусом `Faulted` и мы должны попасть в блок `catch`. Проблема наблюдается когда вызов обработчика проходит через сам `Mediator`. Например, если я сделаю что-то вроде `new TestHandler().Handle(new TestCommand()).Wait();` в `catch` мы попадем.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Автор библиотеки не удосужился вызвать ConfigureAwait(false) ([RequestHandler.cs](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/blob/master/src/MediatR/Internal/RequestHandler.cs#L190)), так что внутри библиотеки произошёл захват контекста, а вы вызовом Wait() заблокировали поток, в который должно вернуться управление, так что произошёл классический deadlock с async/await, можете почитать детальный разбор тут [Еще один аргумент за ConfigureAwait(false) в библиотеках](http://andrey.moveax.ru/post/csharp-async-wait-deadlocks)

Comment: Ну теперь все понятно. Самое интересное, что если создать запрос, который возвращает результат `public class MyRequest: IRequest<MyResult> {}` и вызвать его через библиотеку, то все отработает как надо, даже при вызове метода `Wait()`, т.к. логика обработки таких запросов отличается. Классно, что заметили проблему.

Comment: @sp7 Для IRequest<> там Task получается как Task.FromResult<Unit>, так что вызов получается синхронный. А вам MediatR для какой цели в проекте , как шина для CQRS?

Comment: Ну да, вроде шины для CQRS. Раньше для этих целей использовалась своя инфраструктура, но в последнее время часто слышал про данную библиотеку и просто решил заюзать.